# Print HashMap Values with Stream api

Tags: java, api, stream, hashmap

```
HashMap<String, Double> missions = new HashMap<>();
missions.put("name", 1.0);
missions.put("name1", 2.0);
missions.keySet().stream().forEach(el-> System.out.println(el));
```

This prints only the keys, how do I print the map's values instead?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `entrySet()` (or `values()` if that's what you need) instead of `keySet()`:

```
Map<String, Double> missions = new HashMap<>();
missions.put("name", 1.0);
missions.put("name1", 2.0);
missions.entrySet().stream().forEach(e-> System.out.println(e));
```

Comment: You could pass the method reference directely instead of creating a lambda: `forEach(System.out::println)`. However, it's just a matter of style.

Comment: Yes but in this case I am not sure if what OP wants is value or entry - if it's the latter, then lambda would be a better choice (as you may want to get key or value from an `Entry`).

Comment: ty, how do you remember the stream api commads so well, i cant seem to get the logic behind methods it uses, its like learning a new languege lol

Comment: I just understand the logic behind it. It's also consistent with existing Java APIs.

Comment: Also, it is better practice to [program to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface), like `Map<String, Double> missions = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: @ΔλЛ IDK, keys => `keySet()`, values => `values()`, both => `entrySet()`; doesn't affect the `forEach`. But as I said, it's a style thing—just wanted to mention it.

Answer (score 3):

```
HashMap<String, Double> missions = new HashMap<>();
missions.put("name", 1.0);
missions.put("name1", 2.0);
missions.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
name=1.0
name1=2.0
```

Comment: 100% agree with you. What I thought was, since question is already answered, my answer will help to a person who is looking for a solution can easily locate the answer. But I do agree with you which I learnt something from you, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Stores the values in a list which can later used

missions.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
//print it to standard op

missions.values().forEach(val -> System.out.println(val));
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and refrain from answering code-only. Instead, remember you are not only answering the OP, but also to any future readers (especially when answering 3 year old question). Thus, please [edit] the answer to contain an explanation as to **why** this code works.